# Identify this spaceship fruit collection game starring a levitating fish

Tags: ms-dos, identify-this-game, windows-98, windows-95

Okay this might be a long shot, but I've been looking for this game for over 7 years now and I'm starting to question my sanity. I played this game somewhere between 1998-2003 but it might be a tad older than that. I'm not sure whether or not it was MSDOS or early windows versions.

- It was a topdown game
- One of the first levels (maybe all) was on a kind of space-ship
- You had to collect fruit (lots of it)
- You could open electric fences with keys (?)
- Possibly you were some kind of levitating yellow/orange fish - not sure though
- Possibly wearing sunglasses
- It had a wild futuristic soundtrack

Finding this game would - weird as it may sound - fill a void in my sould that has been there for many many years.

Comment: Might be a better question for Arqade? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So, top down = 2d map? "Possibly wearing sunglasses" - so the character you controlled was a person or similar? "collect fruit ... electric fences" - so you walked around the map to collect fruit and then opened the gates to access more of the map? Did the map scroll or screen flip?

Comment: @bjb I could be wrong, but I thought I heard that Arqade didn't allow "identify this" questions. Probably better to check /r/TipOfMyJoystick and the #identify-a-game channel on the Mobygames Discord if it doesn't pan out here.

Comment: Arqade requires a screenshot for identification questions, but you could try asking on sci fi & fantasy: https://scifi.stackexchange.com given the science fiction setting.